# How do I search for a program in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

When I click the magnifying glass or press the Windows key, sometimes I can search for programs, and sometimes it doesn't work. How can I make it always work to search for programs?

[image]

[image: windows 10 specification]

---

Rebuilding the index did not work.

[image: indexing options]

Comment: This is not the same as https://superuser.com/questions/956161/how-do-you-get-a-program-to-show-up-in-the-windows-10-search-field because it is not about adding a new program to the start menu as the program is already in the start menu but it just doesn't show up in a search.

Comment: Does the answer of [this one](https://superuser.com/q/969860/141595) help?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke No That didn't work and left more than a few errors. The calculator 'calc' could not even be found. https://ghostbin.com/paste/y83rb